# Laravel Compact variable blade file display to syntax error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

Here is my Controller code:

```
 public function method(Request $request){
   $typeType = $request->type; //this variable show 'Booking'

   return view('home.profile',compact('type'));
 }
```

Here is blade file :

```
 @extends('layouts.dashboard')
 @section('page_heading',{{$taskType}})
 @section('section')
    //here some code
 @stop
```

if I use this blade code. then I have got this problem:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' (View:resources/view/home/profile.blade.php)

**if I use this code on blade**

```
 @extends('layouts.dashboard')
 @section('page_heading','{{$taskType}}')
 @section('section')
    //here some code
 @stop
```

then blade file display it:

```
<?php echo e($taskType); ?>
```

I want to display it on blade file:

```
 Booking
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You named the variable `$task`, not `$taskType`

Comment: yes, I'm changing but also show error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you don't need `{{ }}` inside a Blade Directive.

So change that to:

```
 @section('page_heading', $taskType)
```

Comment: If it was your answer, please mark it as best answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public function method(Request $request){
   $typeType = $request->type; //this variable show 'Booking'

   return view('home.profile')->with(['taskType' => $typeType]);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please go ahead and let me know by printing what error are you getting? I mean print_r($typeType) in controller and refresh the page.